# Retrieving values from a Oracle ReturnCursor(few out parameters are ComplexTypes)

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures

I'm a beginner with both java and SQL. Requesting a help, on how to retrieve value from Oracle Cursor type Result Set.

I'm trying to invoke a Stored Procedure from Java and retrieve the result set values for further processing.

Stored Procedure has few IN parameters, say Input_1 and Input_2.
OUT parameter is defined as cursorType defined as,
    OUT_1  NUMBER(10),
    OUT_2  VARCHAR 2 (30 BYTE),
    "OUT_3" AS VARRAY (750) OF Output3_OBJ.
where Output 3_OBJ is defined as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE schema."Output 3_OBJ" AS OBJECT
    (
      ATTRIBUTE_C               VARCHAR2(30),
      VALUE_X                   VARCHAR2(2000 BYTE),
      VALUE_TS                  TIMESTAMP(6),
      VALUE_I                   NUMBER(10),
      OPERAND_C                 VARCHAR2(10)
    )
```

I'm able to retrieve OUT_1 and OUT_2. For getting each sub-element under OUT_3, could you please help me. I've a same structure for another Stored procedure, where I pass these Object types to Oracle using Array Descriptor, Array List and Array. But while retrieving the data from Oracle, i tired various mix and match of this, but not working. Appreciate if someone could help me in this with a sample code. Thanks.

Comment: Could someone please help me?

Comment: this might help? https://www.google.com.au/search?q=retrieve+a+pl%2Fsql+object+with+java&aq=f&oq=retrieve+a+pl%2Fsql+object+with+java Haven't done in it in a while myself but should get you started

Answer (score 0):

You can get in this way

```
stmt.registerOutParameter(3, Types.ARRAY, "Output 3_OBJ");
stmt.execute();
Array array = stmt.getArray(3);
```